# Facebook Graph API Comment Count Suddenly Stopped Working

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Our site uses our own comment system (simple php/mysql) and also the fb comment plugin. I would like to be able to add the comment counts of each to display a single total count of comments from both together. Seems simple enough.

Months ago, I got this working. Then it suddenly stopped working. This morning, I found a new way to do it. Got it working on one page, and by the time I had added the code to all the pages on which we have comments, it was no longer working.

I am pulling my hair out trying to get this working, having virtually zero understanding of json. The FB API explorer gives me an error about auth tokens, but doing what I see recommended has no effect (i.e. creating a new fb app and including the block of auth code they provide).

This is what was working fine at first this am:

```
    $fbcounturl = 'http://www.catalystathletics.com/articles/article.php?articleID=1902';
    $fbjsonurl = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/?fields=share{comment_count}&id=" .$fbcounturl;
    $fbdata = file_get_contents($fbjsonurl);
    $fbarray = json_decode($fbdata, true);
    $fbcomcount = $fbarray['share']['comment_count'];
    print($fbcomcount);
```

Then I could simply add $fbcomcount to the $comCount from our db.

If I just browse to the url, I get the json info fine:

```
    {
    "share": {
    "comment_count": 3
    },
    "id": "http://www.catalystathletics.com/articles/article.php?articleID=1902"
    }
```

But the $fbcomcount is empty.

Here is an example of a page that would use this -
http://www.catalystathletics.com/article/1902/Jumping-Forward-in-the-Snatch-or-Clean-Error-Correction/#comments

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: What you were working with does not include an authorization token. This is a unique key that lets facebook track how many hits to their server you do and limit them according to their policy. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens read their official documentation. You're going to need to append your json url &access_token=app_id|app_secret which you can get by doing what you mentioned the system told you to do before.

Comment: What is `$fbdata`, `$fbarray` and `$fbcomcount` when you run the code?

Comment: @EarleDavies During the brief period of time it was working correctly, it had no token. However, my understanding was that that was indeed the problem, but I was confused by the documentation and other info I could find since there seemed to be several conflicting answers. To pass the token, I can just add the id/secret to the query string in the original $fbjsonurl? I will try that as soon as I have a chance. Thanks.

Comment: @EarleDavies OK, this is now working. Thank you so much. My follow-up question, though, is that is it not a security concern to hardcode the app id and code? I'm guessing there's a way people smarter than me pass those on without having them visible in the source code. Thanks again, very helpful.

Comment: Yeah I know it's really annoying that FB lets you pull stuff from their API with no auth token, and then suddenly revokes it with no warning. It makes you think you don't need one when in reality you do. It is only a security concern if you're putting it into a publicly view able source code such as javascript which you should not do. As long as your putting it into your PHP code, no one can view that. Also, the tokens expire so you'll probably want to look at how to regenerate the tokens automatically. I don't have too much experience doing that but I know it's in the documentation sorry.

Comment: "As long as your putting it into your PHP code, no one can view that" Of course, I don't know what I was thinking. The ID/secret is from an FB app created specifically for this use, so I'm assuming it won't change, but I'll look into that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue recently, Facebook comment count simply stopped working.  Eventually tracked down the error in the returned JSOn response, telling me `Error #4 Application request limit reached`

```
{"error":{"message":"(#4) Application request limit 
reached","type":"OAuthException","is_transient":true,"code":4,"fbtrace_id":"EUNAVRNgnFu"}}`
```

---

Here is a good, detailed response on Facebook Open Graph API limits I found elsewhere:

The Facebook API limit isn't really documented, but apparently it's something like: [**600 calls per 600 seconds, per token & per IP**](http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-Facebook-Open-Graph-API-rate-limit). As the site is restricted, quoting the relevant part:

> After some testing and discussion with the Facebook platform team, there is no official limit I'm aware of or can find in the documentation. However, I've found 600 calls per 600 seconds, per token & per IP to be about where they stop you. I've also seen some application based rate limiting but don't have any numbers.
>
> As a general rule, one call per second should not get rate limited. On the surface this seems very restrictive but remember you can batch certain calls and use the subscription API to get changes.

As you can access the Graph API on the client side via the Javascript SDK; I think if you travel your request for photos from the client, you won't hit any `application limit` as it's the user (each one with unique id) who's fetching data, not your application server (unique ID).

This may mean a huge refactor if everything you do go through a server. But it seems like the best solution if you have so many request (as it'll give a breath to your server).

Else, you can try [`batch` request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/), but I guess you're already going this way if you have big traffic.

---

If nothing of this works, according to the [Facebook Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#features) you should contact them.

> If you exceed, or plan to exceed, any of the following thresholds please [contact us](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=206103619499608) as you may be subject to additional terms: (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day).